# Position of the visible area

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a spherical mesh with a texture and I positioned a perspective camera to see inside out, therefore allowing me to do a 360 view.

```
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(this.fov, $(this.element).width() / $(this.element).height(), 0.1, 1000);
this.camera.setLens(this.fov);
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 80, 50 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: this.texture } ) );
this.mesh.scale.x = -1;
this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(cx, cy, cz));
this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
```

I would like to know how to calculate the view area and position in the mesh that the viewer is currently seeing, a kind of viewable area of the plane.

By viewable area, I mean what the user can see of the image texture in the browser at the current state, kind of `(0,0)(x,y)(400,500)(width,height)` and if the user moves the mouse I would get `(50,0)(x,y)(400,500)(width,height)`,
and if the user zooms in `(50,40)(x,y)(300,400)(width,height)`..
For the width and height I've already seen formulas using camera fov however I couldn't find a solution for the x,y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work to obtain u,v coordinates within your texture based on x,y,z coordinates of the lookat vector of your camera:

```
    var u, v;

    // V coordinate
    if (x == 0 && z == 0)
    {
        if (y > 0)
            v = 1;
        else
            if (y < 0) v = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        v = 0.5 + Math.atan( y / Math.sqrt(x*x + z*z) ) / Math.PI;
    }

    // U coordinate
    if (z == 0)
    {
        if (x < 0)
            u = 0.5;
        if (x > 0)
            u = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        u = 0.25 - Math.atan(x/z) / (2 * Math.PI);
        if (z < 0) u += 0.5;
    }
```

If you need exact pixel positions in the texture, just multiply u and v by width and height of the texture respectively.

Please note that u is not defined when both x and z equal zero.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,. this is really awesome.. i was with a great problem and this works wonderfully.. just another bit of information to complete this.. for someone in need.. for the width and height i used "var vFov = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;
            var height = (2 * Math.tan( vFov / 2 ) * distancetoview)+0.5>>0;
            var width = (height * camera.aspectratio)+0.5>>0;" , it does not give perfect values but closed enough

Comment: Well, it's a bit tricky with width and height because the texture area on the spherical mesh that is projected to a rectangular window is not rectangular. It's cushion-shaped.